# Collection of short stories; in one a spy attempts to escape detection on Mars's moon by moving faster than the spaceship can scan

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to track down a collection of older short stories I read as a kid. I can recall only one of the stories quite clearly.

It involves a spy, telling a story years later, attempting to escape detection by hiding on either Phobos or Deimos. He is being chased by a spaceship, but because of the short horizon and rocky surface, he is able to move about much faster than the spaceship can scan the surface.

I came here because I had just remembered a second story from the same collection, but by the time I wrote the section above it was gone...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like *[Hide and Seek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hide-and-Seek_(short_story))* by Arthur C. Clarke.  It's included in his collection *Expedition to Earth*.

From the Wikipedia summary:

> Kingman then recounts the story (in the third person) of agent K-15 who was fleeing in a space craft with vital information, pursued by the space cruiser Doradus. K-15 was 12 hours from a rendezvous with a capital ship, but the cruiser was only 6 hours behind him. To escape K-15 lands on the moon Phobos, sending his craft on broadcasting a message of his plan. He is left alone on the hostile moon to face the oncoming cruiser. However, despite the apparently overwhelming superiority the cruiser had over a man in a spacesuit armed only with a pistol, the story shows the advantage. The cruiser could only manoeuvre with difficulty so close to Phobos, while K-15 could easily outpace it on the ground. Also, despite the cruiser’s firepower, K-15’s gun gave him the advantage over any men (who would be unarmed) that the cruiser might land. At first K-15 tries to keep to the opposite side of the moon, in case the cruiser opens fire on the surface, but later realizes he is better keeping it in sight, just above his horizon. This continues until the arrival of K-15's rendezvous, and the cruiser is forced to flee, where Kingman’s story ends.

Comment: That is definitely the story. Now I have to track down the collection, I don't think it was ''Expedition'' but The Google will tell me for sure...

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56136